# traverse x number of nodes inorder

Tags: c, binary-tree, traversal

I know this is probably a simple question but it's been a while since I've done any C programming.  I am trying to perform an inorder traversal on x nodes where x is some number I pass to the function.  My inorder function is calling itself recursively and for the life of my I cannot figure how to stop the traversal after its visited x nodes.  Here is my inorder traversal function:

```
void inorder(node h)
 {

     if (h != NULL)
     {
        inorder(h->l);

        printf(" %d\n",h->item);

        inorder(h->r);
     }
      return;

 }
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make the `inorder` function return a number indicating the number of nodes left, then pass the number as parameter to `inorder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - should work for only x number of nodes visited (where the number of nodes visited are the nodes which are the candidates for being printed);

```
int inorder(node h, int x)
 {

     if (h != NULL && x > 0)
     {
        x = inorder(h->l, x);

        if (x > 0) {
           printf(" %d\n",h->item);
           x--;
        }
        if (h->r && x > 0)
           x = inorder(h->r, x);
     }
      return x;

 }
```

[**EDIT**: This code was corrected by **@nhahtdh** after some discussion on the definition of nodes visited and decrementing the value of x. The working test code can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/k9oOkH).

Comment: x is an element that he wants to visit, not in-order visit depth, I think

Comment: I think that he want to visit x number of nodes if I'm not getting the question wrong.

Comment: I think you decrement too much. You should only decrement once, but it seems you decrement x twice per function call (ignoring the recursive call).

Comment: I'm trying to decrement whenever I visit a node so in each function call, we actually visit a left or right node. isn't? I'm thinking now that the node can be null which could be a wrong decrement.

Comment: @nommyravian: You should only decrement once after you `printf`, and you also need to check whether you should print the item, since `x` might reach 0 after visiting the left subtree.

Comment: what I think is that x must be the number of node visited, not number of nodes printed. So every node must be marked as visited when we make a function call with left or right child. I just tested what you're saying and it's printing more nodes than x.

Comment: @nommyravian: I don't know what OP means by number of nodes visited - I take it as the number of nodes that should be printed out. Can you paste your test code on ideone?

Comment: it's here. I did some testing in old code so took time to take out something useful for ideone.
[testcode](http://ideone.com/zCaUmX)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27911/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-nommyravian)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "number of visits" is the number of nodes that you want to print out from the in-order traversal. One solution is to make the `inorder` function return the number of nodes left to be printed, and check against it as you traverse the tree.

```
int inorder(node h, int x)
{
    // I mimic your current code. The code is indeed shorter, but it will
    // do extra recursion, compared to the other approach of checking
    // for the subtree and value of x before the recursive call.
    if (h != NULL && x > 0)
    {
        x = inorder(h->l, x);

        if (x > 0) {
            printf(" %d\n",h->item);
            x--;
        }

        x = inorder(h->r, x);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Another slight variation in implementation is to pass a pointer to an variable that contains `x`, and use it to update the counter. The function doesn't need to return anything if written this way.

```
void inorder(node h, int *x)
{
    // I mimic your current code. The code is indeed shorter, but it will
    // do extra recursion, compared to the other approach of checking
    // for the subtree and value of x before the recursive call.
    if (h == NULL && *x > 0)
    {
        inorder(h->l, x);

        if (*x > 0) {
            printf(" %d\n",h->item);
            (*x)--;
        }

        inorder(h->r, x);
    }
}
```